# loop variable symbol captured by func literal

Tags: go

Why am I getting `loop variable symbol captured by func literal` in the go playground but not during compilation?

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    symbols := []string{"DOGEUSDT", "BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT"}

    for _, symbol := range symbols {

        log.Print("aaa ", symbol)

        // Create a proc for each symbol so we can handle reconnects.
        go func() {

            log.Print("bbb ", symbol)
        
        }()

    }
}
```

Comment: It's valid Go that will compile just fine, but it is an oft encountered programmer mistake that results in behaviour the programmer did not intend. Therefore the `loop variable symbol captured by func literal` message is just a warning issued by go-vet, not the compiler.

Comment: See: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning message alerted by go-vet. `func literal` means anonymous function here. To satisfy the go-vet we need to pass `loop variable` as a parameter.

Check the refactored code below. Working example on playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/lYOez6wZCsB).

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    symbols := []string{"DOGEUSDT", "BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT"}

    for _, symbol := range symbols {

        log.Print("aaa ", symbol)

        // Create a proc for each symbol so we can handle reconnects.
        go func(newSymbol string) {

            log.Print("bbb ", newSymbol )

        }(symbol)

    }
}
```

Comment: An alternative is to shadow the iteration variable within the loop: `symbol := symbol`.